# Get all containers/images using docker-java client library

Tags: java, docker

I have imported docker-java client library.

Using above library how can I get all containers/images available?

Sample code will help a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Able to get containers/images using docker-java client library.

**To get all the images**

```
 DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("http://localhost:2375").build();
 List<Image> images = dockerClient.listImagesCmd().exec();

    for(int i=0; i < images.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(images.get(i));
    }
```

**To get all the containers**

```
import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.InspectContainerResponse;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.ListContainersCmd;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.ListImagesCmd;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Container;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Image;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder;

String localDockerHost = SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS ? "tcp://localhost:2375" : "unix:///var/run/docker.sock";
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(localDockerHost).build();
List<Container> containers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().exec();

    for(int i=0; i < containers.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(containers.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: where is this full project to this code sample